# Why is addition defined, and not implied, on quotient spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, quotient-spaces

Small question. In chapter 3, section E, page 96 of "Linear Algebra Done Right", addition in quotient vector spaces is defined this way:
[image]

I understand why scalar multiplication has to be defined, because multiplying a subset of a vector space with a scalar was not defined. But why can addition of affine subsets be said to work this way, if the sum of subsets of a vector space was already defined?

[image]

$v+U, w+U$ are both subsets of a vector space $V$, so $(v+U)+(w+U)$ is the set containing all possible sums of elements of $v+U$ with elements of $w+U$. Shouldn't the statement $(v+U)+(w+U)=(v+w)+U$ be a theorem?

Comment: You can have many different "additions" defined for a set.  Here, I interpret the book to merely be selecting a canonical choice for one of many possible additions to use, and such a choice would be a definition moreso than a theorem.  That it coincides with earlier chosen additions of related objects is a convenience but not a necessity.

Comment: The addition defined on a scalar and a subset does not define the addition on subsets. (Though it defines a *natural* addition.)

Comment: Nice question. One reason might be that v is not a subset of the vector space but an element. So while {v}+U is defined before, v+U is not.

Comment: @JMoravitz, this would be the best answer if it was one.

Comment: It's worth noting that quotienting is used in many other algebraic structures, and in some cases, the subset operation is not the same as the quotient operation. Consider multiplication in the integers modulo $12$, for instance. There we have $(2 + \langle 12\rangle)(7 + \langle 12\rangle) = 2+\langle 12\rangle$ by the quotient product, but the subset product clearly doesn't contain $2$. So it makes some sense to keep the two notions separate, even if they happen to yield all the same results in a particular context.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In fact, regardless of what others are saying, the two definitions of addition are equivalent for cosets of a subspace.

We need different notation for the two additions. Let's say $$(a+U)+(b+U)=(a+b)+U$$is the "coset-wise sum", while $$A\oplus B=\{a+b:a\in A, b\in B\}$$ is the "subset sum".

> > **Triviality.** If $V$ is a vector space, $U$ is a subspace of $V$ and $a,b\in V$ then $(a+U)+(b+U)=(a+U)\oplus (b+U)$.

Proof: Suppose first that $x\in (a+U)\oplus (b+U)$. The definitions show that there exist $u_1,u_2\in U$ with $x=(a+u_1)+(b+u_2)$; hence $x=(a+b)+(u_1+u_2)\in (a+b)+U=(a+U)+(b+U)$.

Otoh if $x\in (a+U)+(b+U)=(a+b)+U$ then $x=(a+b)+u=(a+u)+(b+0)\in (a+U)\oplus (b+U)$.

Comment: I was wrong and deleted my posts. Turns out the definition of addition of subsets I learned isn't the same as the one given by that book.

Comment: @Compacto I can't imagine what that other definition of the sum of two subsets might be. Are you sure it wasn't a definition of the word "span" that you were using here??? (I conjecture this because for example the plane _is_ the span of two parallel lines...)

Comment: Probably, that's how we used to call It "the sum subset".

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 6):

You are correct that the definition of addition of cosets is a special case of the definition of arbitrary subsets. I have on many occasions encountered what might be referred to as 'non-minimal' definitions, where certain parts are redundant and can be deduced from earlier results.

Sometimes, like in this case, multiple definitions are given when one could easily just refer to the most general definition and point out that the special case follows easily from it. I guess it is a matter of style, but personally I think if overlapping definitions are given in the same text, the author should at the very least explicitly outline their interdependence so the reader knows there if there is any risk of using inconsistent definitions.

The author might have presented it this way in this particular case to keep an individual chapter relatively self-contained, since most readers will not read cover-to-cover. Having said all this, I should point out that *Linear Algebra Done Right* does seem to be a very good book to learn from :)

Answer (score 3):

The answer of @DavidCUllrich addresses your question of whether the statement should be a theorem; indeed, yes it should.

But you have also asked a subtly different question: *Why can addition of affine subsets be said to work this way, if the sum of subsets was already defined?*

The short answer is: Commutativity of addition is used strongly to prove that the two definitions are equivalent; whereas Definition 3.86 works even in noncommutative situations where Definition 1.36 does not apply.

To put this another way, Definition 3.86 generalizes to produce operations on quotient sets in other branches of algebra, in situations where Definition 1.36 definitely does *not* generalize.

In particular, in group theory, consider a group $G$ with group operation written multiplicatively as $g \cdot h$. Given a normal subgroup $N \triangleleft G$, the group operation on the quotient group $G / N$ is defined by
$$(*) \qquad\qquad (g \cdot N) \cdot (h \cdot N) = (g \cdot h) \cdot N
$$
But in this group theoretical context where the group operation *need not* be commutative, the operation defined in $(*)$ **cannot** be made to agree with any generalization of the subset operation in Definition 3.36.

Comment: So what's wrong with the obvious generalization $A_1 \cdot \ldots \cdot A_n = \{ a_1 \cdot \ldots \cdot a_n : a_1 \in A_1, \ldots, a_n \in A_n \}$? The definition $(*)$ agrees with it, which seems to contradict your claim.

Comment: A better example would be multiplication in a quotient ring. For $R$ a ring (even a commutative one) and $I$ a (two-sided) ideal, we do not always have $xy+I = \{ab : a \in x+I,\ b \in y+I \}$. For example, $R = \mathbb{Z}$, $I = 5 \mathbb{Z}$, $x=2$ and $y=3$. The coset $6+5 \mathbb{Z}$ contains $1$, but $1$ cannot be factored as $ab$ with $a \equiv 2 \bmod 5$ and $b \equiv 3 \bmod 5$.

Answer (score 3):

Other answers give several good reasons already; here is one more, not yet mentioned.

**Conceptually, we often think of the cosets $v+U$ (or more generally, equivalence classes in a quotient) as a different kind of thing from arbitrary subsets of a space.**  We’re *thinking* of the coset/quotient space $V/U$ as a separate object in its own right, not as living inside the power set $\mathcal{P}(V)$, even though formally $V/U \subseteq \mathcal{P}(V)$.  So we think of the operations on $V/U$ as defined in themself — we don’t stop to consider whether they’re a special case of the operations on $\mathcal{P}(V)$.  In this case the two definitions do agree; but there are other places where the operations you use on a quotient don’t agree with the setwise operations on the power-set (e.g. cosets in a general group/ring/module, such as mod-$n$ arithmetic $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$).

This way of thinking — viewing different sets as separate objects, even though they may have some elements in common — is widespread and important in maths, but often not explicitly discussed or taught. It’s more explicitly discussed in programming, as a kind of *abstraction*, or *implementation-independence*.  Formally, unicode-strings (or whatever) are just certain sequences of bytes.  But (in many modern programming languages) you declare them a separate *type* of object, and you deliberately don’t allow byte-sequence functions to act directly on unicode-strings.

Comment: The operations defined on the quotient $\mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z}$ do agree with the setwise operations and this also works for any other example I can think of.

Comment: @Adayah: Addition does, but multiplication doesn’t, unless I’m very much mistaken.  In $\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}\Z/2\Z$, we have $[0].[0] = [0]$.  But $[0]$ is $2\Z$, and under the setwise product, $2\Z.2\Z = 4\Z$.

Comment: You're right. For the multiplication to work we would have to take the unique coset containing the setwise result, i.e. $(r+I)(s+I) \subseteq a+I \iff a+I = rs+I$.

Answer (score 0):

The quotient space is given by $V/U = \{v+U\mid v\in V\}$, where $v+U = \{v+u\mid u\in U\}$ is a coset. Note that $v+U = (v+u)+U$ for each $u\in U$ and so the coset representative $v$ is not uniquely determined.

Addition is defined as

$(v+U) + (w+U) := (v+w) + U.$

What needs to be shown is well-definedness, i.e. if you take other representatives of the cosets, $v'+U = v+U$ and $w'+U=w+U$, then the result is the same:
$(v+w)+U = (v'+w')+U$.